# Does English have a fairly fixed word order?

Tags: sentence-construction

English has a  fairly fixed word order. Is that sentence true or false?

Comment: what do you mean about that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by **"fairly"**? Your question is to broad, see the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316647/does-english-have-a-fairly-fixed-word-order#comment594200_316647) of the community bot? **I** made that comment. It's like asking "Give me some **good** English learning resources". What does "good" mean? Please define "fairly".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I believe that if **you** can understand it, anyone else in the world can.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, so you're expecting me to say "thank you"? For correcting a meaningless typo?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Um, so you think that Hagar Mamdouh doesn't know how to spell "too"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So you think that I don't know how to spell "too" and you're here to teach me?

Answer (score 3):

Well the word "fairly" isn't really sufficiently well-defined to answer that. That said, I think it's safe to say that word order *does* have importance in English. In particular, in comparative terms I reckon, based on my albeit very limited knowledge, that:

> Word order in English is more important compared with many other languages.

On the other hand, I'll note that:

> English word order is more important compared with many other languages.

Then again, I'd be remiss if I didn't also point out that:

> Compared with many other languages, word order is more important in English.

So, it depends on the sentence in question.
As Yoda might say: Important order is. But many exceptions there are. Yesssss.

Comment: For Yoda plus one I vote.

Comment: But this question was mentioned in the exam for my university, knowing that the answer is found in the professor's book on the subject, that the order of words in the English language is fixed, but based on what I took from MWO and the change in word order, I suspected this question and I want to know whether it is true that  Somewhat fairly fixed or fixed.

Comment: @HagarMamdouh If you'd given us that context, we could have answered better. English doesn't have much morphology left, so it's becoming analytic, like Chinese, and its word order (and particle usage) is comparatively rigid, also like Chinese. But it's not **that** rigid. There are [all kinds of movement rules like Extrapositions, Dislocations, Clefts, etc.](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) that have the effect of changing the order of constituents drastically. Native speakers can get away with a lot.

Comment: Please, what about this question? I..... wear a helmet before I was allowed down the mine.Which is correct could or had to or must or ought to

Comment: @HagarMamdouh - don't ask a new question in a comment

Comment: @HagarMamdouh Please ask a new question instead of asking that in a comment.

Comment: @HagarMamdouh: Even most native speakers are uncertain about [the past tense of "must"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/is-must-ever-grammatical-as-a-past-tense-verb). But as you apparently aren't clear about the difference between ***must*** and ***ought to***, I suggest you look into that before checking out the ELU question I just linked to. There's also [What is the past form of the modal verb "must"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528458/what-is-the-past-form-of-the-modal-verb-must) with more useful stuff from Prof JohnLawler.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted tkp’s excellent answer, but your comment to that answer indicates to me that your question is based on a misconception.

Few things in language are absolute.

The importance of word order varies among languages. Compared to Latin, word order in English is much more fixed. Compared to French, word order in English is about equally flexible.

> John hit Mary

> Mary hit John

Those two sentences have completely different meanings, and the difference is determined solely by the order of the words.

In more complex sentences, word order is more flexible. if you want to be understood, however, my advice is to place the subject before the verb in indicative clauses. But you have your choice about placing an adverb before the verb modified or after the direct object.

> John dearly loved her

> John loved her dearly.

This all goes back to the vagueness of “fairly” in your question. Word order is important in English but not absolutely fixed.

Comment: Do you mean that the correct answer is that English has fairly fixed word order? or the  question is not correct?

Comment: The present study aims at investigating the form and function of word order (WO) and word-order variations or marked word orders (MWOS) in
English. First, what is word order? Simply speaking, word order is the way in which the subject (S), Object (0), and Verb (V) are arranged in a sentence in a language.
English has a fixed word order. Sentences in English use a standard general order, which can be simply explained as: 
He bought a car. (1) Subject (2) Verb (3)Object 
This is what is stated in the book of the professor.

Comment: @HagarMamdouh So what do you mean by "fairly"? Although we've been telling you in the comment to explain what "fairly" means in your question, you just keep using that word!

Comment: You seem to be questioning what someone wrote in a book, but never cite nor quote the actual words that you want to have discussed. It seems that “word order” as discussed in whatever book you are concerned about is limited to subject-verb-object in indicative sentences. Yes, that is the normal word order well over 99% of the time. it is not, however, completely invariant.